# Android API to measure Power level transmitted to speaker

Tags: android

I would like to measure power transmitted to speaker/headset by playing music on the phone using android code . I do not want sound felt at microphone to be measured because it may contain noise as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the Android SDK to measure this, sorry.